# How to match an out of order string with Javascript regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've written a live filter in javascript that takes a value from a field and hides the rows in a table that do not match.

The RegEx I use for this is very simple: /inputValue/i

Although this works great it only matches characters that are in order. For example:

```
inputValue = test
string to match = this is a test sentence
```

This example would match, but if I tried:

```
inputValue = this sentence
string to match = this is a test sentence
```

This won't match because the input value is out of order.

How would I go about writing a RegEx that is in order but can skip words?

Here is the loop I currently use:

```
for (var i=0; i < liveFilterDataArray.length; i++) {

  var comparisonString = liveFilterDataArray[i],
    comparisonString = comparisonString.replace(/['";:,.\/?\\-]/g, '');

  RE = eval("/" + liveFilterValue + "/i");

  if (comparisonString.match(RE)) {
    rowsToShow.push(currentRow);
  }
  if(currentRow < liveFilterGridRows.length - 1) {
    currentRow++;
  } else {
    currentRow = 0;
  }
}
```

Many thanks for your time.

Chris

Comment: perhaps `RE = eval("/" + liveFilterValue.split(" ").join("|") + "/i");`

Comment: Thats done the trick with 1 caveat, it finds results containing any of the words i,e. 

inputValue = this sentence
1st string to match = this is a test sentence
2nd string to match = this is a test paragraph

It will match on both strings because the word "this" occurs in both when it should only match the 1st string because that contains both words.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is recommended to Use [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead of eval.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/3uhcQ/)

```
var words = liveFilterValue.split(" ");
var searchArg = (words.length==1)?words:words.join(".*")+'|'+words.reverse().join(".*")
var RE = new RegExp(searchArg,"i");
```

It will create `this.*sentence|sentence.*this/i`

remove `+'|'+words.reverse().join(".*")` if you only want to find `this.....sentence` and not `sentence....this`

Answer (score 0):

You could split the input string on spaces and then run the filter sequentially for each word.